# Converting HTMLElement to a React Element, and keeping any event listeners

Tags: reactjs, dom

Rendering some JSON data into a set of collapsible HTML elements is EASY using a library like **renderjson** (npm package) for Vanilla JS

```
const data = { sample: [1, 2, 3, 4], data: { a: 1, b: 2, c: ["hello", null] } };
const rjson = renderjson(data);
document.getElementById('to-render').append(rjson);
```

---

### In The react world

However, **renderjson** returns an HTMLElement, NOT A STRING. Please note that I'm not JUST trying to convert HTML strings into react HTML here. I'm trying to convert the HTMLElement into a real ReactElement.

So, I actually managed to do this, but since I'm parsing the HTMLElement into a string, all the onClick event listeners generated by **renderjson** on the + and - handles (to open or collapse the json) are LOST in the process....

Does anyone have any idea on how to convert a HTMLElement object into React Element, keeping all the original event handlers?

---

I guess, the real question here is: how can the **renderjson** package be "repackaged" to become React friendly?

[Here is a codesandbox to make it easier to see what I'm talking about here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/xoz7q9jv3o)

Comment: Why not place the handlers in a static parent container?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by static parent container...thanks for the reply though!

Comment: @b00stup Do you have achieved this? I am stuck on the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, I keep running into similar issues with non-React JS libraries that return DOM elements. These libraries should be ported to React, but if you don't want to do that, you can use [`findDomNode()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode) to get a DOM (not React) node, and append your `HTMLElement` there. Please note that in the official docs, its use is discouraged because "it pierces the component abstraction". Anyways, in your example, you could add a wrapper class:

```
class JsonTreeWrapper extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const renderedJson = renderjson(this.props.data);

    const container = findDOMNode(this);
    container.appendChild(renderedJson);
  }

  render() {
    return <div/>;
  }
}
```

what this does is render a `div`, and when the component mounts it finds the `div` and adds the `HTMLElement` generated by your library there. Simple.

In your `App`, you can use it like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> Inside the react world </h1>
        <JsonTreeWrapper data={data}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This way your listeners will be working just fine.

Codesandbox didn't work for me, but you can check a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ecafgw). I hope this helps!

Comment: is this still valid? I found that ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component) was deprecated  according to the official docs

Comment: if you visit the link to the method above (that's from reactjs.org), it says that "It has been deprecated **in StrictMode**.". In any case, use of this method is discouraged because "it pierces the component abstraction". Nasty thing to do, but it's a quick hack. It was good enough for a prototype I was building. Can't think of a clean way to convert an HTMLElement object into a React Element