# How to create a react component from a DOM node?

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-component

I would like to create a react component from a DOM node (pretty small one, nothing crazy), for example:

```
//this footer is plain html and css, not a react component
const Footer = document.getElementById("#anAwesomeFooter")
```

and in some way use it anywhere in my app:

```
// before doing some magic
<Main>
 <Footer />
<Main />
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: You can only take which is a text from DOM to in React. React elements are not static elements. They are just Javascript functions -- Like `React.createElement('div')`. Maybe you can do parse and convert to React elements with your function. What's your goal to do?

Comment: Hi @Mustafa, I'm working in a react app which is a child app of a parent app (not react app, is liquid shopify) and I want to use an announcement bar which is placed in the parent app (out of react) in the child app, maybe can I do it with a portal?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to answer. I'm not sure, are you still trying to fix on this. I haven't try but React Portal feature isn't for that i guess. React Portal helps us to create another JSX element out of component of children. I still thinking about that you can do that with another ReactDOM.render function. When you mount your React Component then inside you can use ReactDOM.render(document.getElementById('#targetDOM')) in componentDidMount lifecycle function. Thus, it going to trigger another DOM element to create another React tree.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React from 'react';

const Footer = () => (<div>Footer of some div outside the Main component hierarchy</div>);

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const elementToAttach = document.getElementById('someElementId');
  return (
    <Main>
      {React.createPortal(Footer, this.elementToAttach)}
    </Main>
  );
};
```

You can do the getElementById in the constructor to run only once, but thats depends if you know the element is already rendered

Comment: Actually is the other way around Footer is attached into this.elementToAttach (the container) , but I got your idea!

Answer (score 0):

I think the closets you can get, is getting the content of the DOM node in the `componentDidMount`, and append it to a rendered element. This question and answers is related.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53897595/4703833

Comment: the solution uses: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component), it receives a component as a parameter but I have a node DOM (HTMLDivElement)

Comment: maybe a parse can be used, something like https://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm for very small DOM nodes